# Jquery effect ripples doesn't work on background-attachment: fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So basically that it - the effect ripples(https://sirxemic.github.io/jquery.ripples/) doesn't work with background-attachment: fixed . Anyone knows how to work around this with having attachment:fixed and still having this effect working?

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Comment: Not sure you can do anything about this but follow the api

Comment: you could report it as an [issue on the github page](https://github.com/sirxemic/jquery.ripples/issues) - the author may have ideas, or may know for a fact that it's unpossible

Comment: You don't really say what the issue is, just that it "doesn't work." Have you got a jsFiddle for it, or a link so we can see what the actual issue is?

Comment: @Whothehellisthat Let's say http://mkey.lt/STARK/  if you set background-attachment: fixed; It stops working

Comment: Just looks like a bug. It's trying to `.getClientBoundRects()` from `window` when it usually gets it from `body`, the actual thing that's being rippled. Speak to the developers about it.

Comment: I assume you've tried actually adding `background-attachment:fixed` to the source files, and not just through dev tools? That may have different results.

Comment: http://mkey.lt/STARK/withAttached/  -Yes, i tried.

Comment: Thank you - will try to talk to the developer about this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the ripples bug. I contacted the developer in github and he fixed it. Case closed.